# PNG cropping increases file size

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, python-imaging-library, compression, png

I have a set of PNG 240x240px images (~1Gb of images) for training a classification algorithm and I need to crop the bottom 26px (resulting in 240x214px) from those images, which contain some number and date which I do not want in the final image set.

I've started with a python library named Pillow, but soon realised that after reading, cropping and resaving the PNG images the file size increased about 5x (~5Gb of images).

I think I know it will not affect the outcome of the CNN, but mainly the time it will take to train it, but I still wonder if there is a way to better compress or any other method to keep the original file size.

I will attach one image before (11Kb) and after (74Kb) processing as an example.

[image]
[image]

I'll also attach a [link to imgur](https://imgur.com/a/LVy3tfp) where the images are in their original PNG format.

This is the code I've used for cropping the images:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image

def cropp_images_in_folder(from_folder, to_folder):
    for image in listdir(from_folder):
        if image.endswith(".png"):
            full_path = from_folder + image
            im = Image.open(full_path)
            im1 = im.crop((0, 0, 240, 214))
            full_path = to_folder + image
            im1.save(full_path, optimize=True, compress_level = 9)
            i += 1
```

Comment: Imgur converts images above a certain size to JPEG. So all we can see here in your post are two JPEG images. This doesn’t really help understand your problem.

Comment: Are you sure the input images are PNG and not JPEG with a (wrong) PNG extension? You can look at the first few bytes of the file, for a PNG file this should be `\211 P N G \r \n \032 \n`. JPEG files start with the two bytes 0xFF 0xD8.

Comment: I've added a link to imgur where I've uploaded the images and they're both in PNG format @CrisLuengo

Comment: Unrelated. PNG is not generally a good format for photographs - it is better suited to computer-generated images with relatively large blocks of unvarying, solid colour rather than photographic nuances of colour. There's a reason why JPEG comes from the *"Joint **Photographic** Experts Group"* and why nearly all digital cameras record images in JPEG.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a set of PNG 240x240px images ...

The first image is not PNG. It's JPEG. The second image is PNG. If you want a more comparable size for the second image, then compress it to JPEG as well.

Comment: I've added a link to imgur where I've uploaded the images and they're both in PNG format @mark-adler

Comment: Again, your before image on imgur is a JPEG, and your after image on imgur is a PNG. _They are not both in PNG format._

Answer (score 0):

Just to emphasise the point that Mark has already made, the original file is a JPEG, the cropped file is a PNG.

I downloaded the two file from https://imgur.com/a/LVy3tfp

```
$ unzip -l ~/Downloads/Imgur\ Album\ Before\ and\ after\ PNG\ crop.zip 
Archive:  /home/paul/Downloads/Imgur Album Before and after PNG crop.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    74877  2024-03-11 12:44   1 - j5iIxA6.png
    10910  2024-03-11 12:44   2 - 4bGrdyP.jpg
---------                     -------
    85787                     2 files
```

File extensions suggest a JPEG & a PNG but let's double check by seeing what is actually stored in these file.

```
$ unzip ~/Downloads/Imgur\ Album\ Before\ and\ after\ PNG\ crop.zip 
Archive:  ~/Downloads/Imgur Album Before and after PNG crop.zip
  inflating: 1 - j5iIxA6.png         
  inflating: 2 - 4bGrdyP.jpg         

$ file *
1 - j5iIxA6.png: PNG image data, 240 x 214, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
2 - 4bGrdyP.jpg: JPEG image data, baseline, precision 8, 240x240, components 3
```

Yep, you have a JPEG file & a PNG file.

Did you upload the wrong version of the original file?

Comment: Yup, I now see on my computer that one of them is JPEG indeed, my bad, sorry for wasting your time. I've downloaded both of them from the internet and they'd downloaded with a .png extension and I assumed they're PNG images, turns out they're not.